# How to do 2 equal statements upon certain conditions?

Tags: php, equals

I need to use different modules based on what value the $what variable holds.  There are 2 variables; me and others.  If $what = me i want them to see me.php an if $what = others i want them to see others.php.  I don't know how to update the snippet that will also take $what = other scenario under consideration.

How to do that?

```
  $what = "me";

  if ( $q === $what ) {
require("me.php");
  } else {
  require("all.php");
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [elseif](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) statement.

```
 $what = "me";

 if ( $q === $what ) {
    require("me.php");
 } elseif ($what === "others") {
    require("all.php");
 } else {  // optional "catch all condition"
   die("Should not be here");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks lotus I had to answer the phone & got distracted, kudos to you.

Answer (score 2):

You need [**`else if`**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php).

---

That said, an improvement in terms of extensibility would be to use an array as map:

```
$pages = array(
    'me' => 'me.php',
    'others' => 'others.php'
);

$page = 'all.php';

if(isset($pages[$q])) {
    $page = $pages[$q];
}

require($page);
```

Comment: add else if after the } and start it over again...?

Comment: @AAA: Follow the link and have a look at the example ;)

Comment: elseif is favorable. See the note on manpage between the 2 examples. ;)

Answer (score 1):

$what = "me";

```
if($what == 'me' ){
     require("me.php");
}
elseif($what == 'others'{
     require('others.php')
}
else{
    // There was no variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
if ( $q === "me") {
    require("me.php");
} elseif ( $q === "others" ) {
    require( "others.php" );
} else {
    require("all.php");
}
```

Comment: Not that I want to nitpick or anything but elsif should be favored over else if. Read the note between the 2 examples on the man page to see why this is so.

Comment: Do you mean `elseif`? Yeah I put that first, but wasn't sure which was preferred. I'll update. Thanks, for that - never realised it made a difference, but then, I rarely use the colon if-notation

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to do that, the simplest being

```
if ($what=="me")
    require('me.php');
else
    require('all.php');
```

or, in case other values might be added in the future, you could do a switch statement

```
switch ($what) {
    case 'me':
        require('me.php');
        break;
    case 'others':
        require('all.php');
        break;
    default:
        require('all.php');
        break;
}
```

In the above case, I assume that showing the all page by default if something goes wrong is the most secure, unless you have something like error.php

Answer (score 0):

You **could** use else if.

```
if ($a == "a") {
   // Do something
}
elseif ($a == "b") {
   // Do something else
}
else {
    // Do something
}
```

You **should** use an [switch](http://php.net/switch) here.

```
switch($a) {
   case "a":
       // Do something
       break;
   case "b":
       // Do something
       break;
   default:
       // Do Something
       break;
}
```